# How to create to create a symlink of a git repo on windows??

Tags: windows, git, github, terminal, symlink

Is it possible to create a symlink of git repo on windows so that i don't have to clone a repo.

> means without cloning a repo can i just edit a foriegn repo
>   (friends repo) from my windows computer using symlink.

Actually i don't know such procedure, if any one can tell me how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Open git bash and write this command:

```
git worktree add /<path>/<name>
```

for example:

```
git worktree add /tmp/link2

# find out where is the folder:
mount 

The 3rd line will show you the path on the disk
```

Now you will have second folder with reference to the original repository.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying, but i'm still stuck in the same position.i did that and it also created the repo as you suggested but changes aren't replicating :(